# Remover ELEMENTO atrás de Iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Uso uma ferramenta de BI da microsoft e nessa ferramenta crio gráficos dinâmicos. Uma das formas de compartilhar esses gráficos é através do uso de um *Iframe* através de um um portal. Quando recebo o frame com os dados dados do gráfico desenvolvido tem um ícone compartilhamento do gráfico criado e eu gostaria de remover esse elemento.

Tentei criar um script assim:

```
function setDisabled() {
  document.getElementById("glyphicon glyphicon-share-twitter glyph-small icon").disabled = true;
}
```

`glyphicon glyphicon-share-twitter glyph-small icon` = Ícone que quero remover.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

O `getElementById` é usado para pegar elementos pelos IDs e não pelas classes.

Por exemplo:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById("test").disabled = true;
}, 1000);
```

```html
<input id="test">
```

Existe o `getElementsByClassName` que pega elementos pelo conjunto de classes, precisa ter um pelo menos, cada item da classe é divido por um espaç, por exemplo:

```js
 console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("foo").length);
 console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("baz").length);
 console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("bar").length);
```

```html
<input class="foo baz bar">
```

Veja que todos retornam 1 em .length, mesmo `foo` estando no começo, `baz` estando no meio e `bar` estando no final, pois o `getElementsByClassName` trabalha pelo item separado por espaços.

Nem sempre é possível manipular o conteúdo de um iframe, isso afeta as politicas de segurança, todavia se o iframe for do mesmo domínio que o seu então pode tentar usar assim:

Supondo que o HTML seja algo como:

```
<iframe id="ID_DO_IFRAME"></iframe>
```

No javascript pode-se usar o [`contentWindow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/contentWindow), deve ficar algo como (desta maneira ele vai remover todos itens que tiverem esta classe):

```
function setDisabled() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("ID_DO_IFRAME").contentWindow;

  var shareBtns = iframe.document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon-share-twitter");
  for (var i = shareBtns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    shareBtns[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

ou com `querySelector` acaso seja apenas um item, assim remove só o primeiro encontrado:

```
function setDisabled() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById("ID_DO_IFRAME").contentWindow;

  iframe.document.querySelector("glyphicon-share-twitter").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

Se o elemento não estiver dentro do IFRAME, então faça simplesmente isto:

```
function setDisabled() {
  var shareBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("glyphicon-share-twitter");
  for (var i = shareBtns.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    shareBtns[i].disabled = true;
  }
}
```

### Conclusão

Não saia usando as funções aleatoriamente, aprenda primeiro o que elas fazem realmente, ou seja, **SEMPRE leia a documentação**, isto para qualquer linguagem, aqui esta alguns links sobre DOM, aprenda como funciona cada função antes de usa-las:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/forms
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByTagName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Guilherme Nascimento obrigado pela resposta,Melhor detalhamento impossível.
Porem o frame não esta no mesmo domínio que o meu , então creio que não sera possível manipular o conteúdo... 
Sera que tem outra saída ?